# Delete thumbnails on server of deleted product on Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

when I delete a product on prestashop, in the server, the original image is deleted, but not all the thumbnails. What can I do if I want to delete all the thumbnails on the server of all the deleted products?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Product's images are listed in `ps_image` table. If you want to make sure that all deleted products images are erased you should do an script that delete all images from `/img/p/` folder that are not in `ps_image` table. Take care with product's images format because images will be repeated for each image format with different size.

Good luck.